# How to deserialize JSON from Kafka Consumer Record

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, jackson-databind

I'm looking to access some fields on a Kafka Consumer record. I'm able to receive the event data which is a Java object i.e `ConsumerRecord(topic = test.topic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 0, CreateTime = 1660933724665, serialized key size = 32, serialized value size = 394, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = db166cbf1e9e438ab4eae15093f89c34, value = {"eventInfo":...})`.
I'm able to access the eventInfo values which comes back as a json string. I'm fairly new to Kotlin and using Kafka so I'm not entirely sure if this is correct but I'm looking to basically access the fields in `value` but I can't get rid of an error that appears when trying to use `mapper.readValue` which is:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
```

```
import com.afterpay.shop.favorites.model.Product
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.Record
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener
import org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class KafkaConsumer {

    @KafkaListener(topics = ["test.topic"], groupId = "group-id")
    fun consume(consumerRecord: ConsumerRecord<String, Any>, ack: Acknowledgment) {
        val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
        val value = consumerRecord.value()
        val record = mapper.readValue(value, Product::class.java)
        println(value)
        ack.acknowledge()
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

First, change `ConsumerRecord<String, Any>` to `ConsumerRecord<String, Product>`, then change `value.deserializer` in your consumer config/factory to use `JSONDeserializer`

Then your `consumerRecord.value()` will already **be** a `Product` instance, and you don't need an ObjectMapper

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#json-serde

---

Otherwise, if you use `StringDeserializer`, change `Any` to `String` so that the `mapper.readValue` argument types are correct.